# pnpm add sqlite3 Unknown options: 'runtime', 'target', 'dist-url'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm, electron

This is normal:

```bash
npm install sqlite3 --runtime=electron --target=24.2.0 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers
```

This is wrong:

```bash
pnpm add sqlite3 --runtime=electron --target=24.2.0 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers

# >> ERROR   ERROR  Unknown options: 'runtime', 'target', 'dist-url'
```

How to install using pnpm?

[node-sqlite3 - Custom builds and Electron](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3)